# How to I append the updated data after load more button using selenium (Webscraping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

After running my code, I am not getting the "updated" data after clicking the load more button. I tried alot of times & I am not sure what is wrong with my code. I am supposed to have a list of data after the load more button runs in python. However, I am only getting the data before button was clicked which i appended in the list.

```
class RunChromeTests():
    def test(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        chrome_options.add_argument("-incognito")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")

    
        # Download the chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads 
        # and find the driver location in your computer
        chrome_path = r"path"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        final = []
    
    
            
        ### Enter your url to scrape but change the page number to {a} 
        driver.get("https://www.burpple.com/search/sg?q=Newly+Opened&type=places")
        content = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
            
        loadmore = driver.find_element_by_id("masonryViewMore-btn")
        j = 0
        final1=[]
       
        try:
            while loadmore.is_displayed():
                loadmore.click()
                time.sleep(2)
                lrec = soup.find_all("span",{"searchVenue-header-name-name headingMedium"})
                #loadmore.is_displayed()
                newlist = lrec[j:]
                print(lrec)
                #print(newlist)
                for rec in newlist:
                    name = rec.text
                    #print(name)
                    final1.append(name)
                print(final1)
                j = len(lrec)+1
                #final1.append(name)
                time.sleep(5)
                #print(j)
                #
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
chromed = RunChromeTests()
chromed.test()
```

Output:
['Kotuwa', 'Smoochie Creamery', "Evan's Kitch", 'Plus Coffee Joint', '800° Woodfired Pizza (KINEX)', "Sarah's Loft", 'nicher (Springleaf)', 'First Story Cafe', 'Tucela Gelato', 'Ri Ri Cha', 'Unatoto', 'Royal Palm (Meat & Dine)']

Correct Output:
['Kotuwa', 'Smoochie Creamery', "Evan's Kitch", 'Plus Coffee Joint', '800° Woodfired Pizza (KINEX)', "Sarah's Loft", 'nicher (Springleaf)', 'First Story Cafe', 'Tucela Gelato', 'Ri Ri Cha', 'Unatoto', 'Royal Palm (Meat & Dine)', 'Flourish Bakehouse','Equate Coffee (Orchard Central)', 'TAG Espresso (Raffles City)', 'Arc-En-Ciel Patisserie', 'Enjoy Eating House & Bar (Stevens),'SAGE By Yasunori Doi (Orchard Plaza)','Hellu Coffee','Pestle & Mortar Society',... ]

... -> signifies & many more

Comment: you wrote `StaleElementReferenceException` except statement. When you click that button im pretty sure it becomes stale. so you probably get the first restaurants in the list and it triggers stale element exception. Just checked the list again. Im pretty sure thats what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the page source in every time you clicked on `Lode More` button.
and keep checking whether name is exists in the list if not then added.

Use infinite loop and check if `load more` button exists, if so click else break the loop.

code:

```
final1=[]
driver.get ("https://www.burpple.com/search/sg?q=Newly+Opened&type=places")
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for item in soup.select("span.searchVenue-header-name-name.headingMedium"):
        if not item.text in final1:
            final1.append(item.text)
    try:
       WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "masonryViewMore-btn"))).click()
       time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break
print("Total number of elements:  {}".format(len(final1)))
print(final1)
```

you need to import below library.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Output:**

```
Total number of elements:  161
['Plus Coffee Joint', 'Kotuwa', 'Smoochie Creamery', "Evan's Kitch", '800° Woodfired Pizza (KINEX)', "Sarah's Loft", 'nicher (Springleaf)', 'First Story Cafe', 'Tucela Gelato', 'Ri Ri Cha', 'Unatoto', 'Royal Palm (Meat & Dine)', 'Flourish Bakehouse', 'TAG Espresso (Raffles City)', 'Equate Coffee (Orchard Central)', 'Arc-en-ciel Pâtisserie', 'Enjoy Eating House & Bar (Stevens)', 'SAGE by Yasunori Doi (Orchard Plaza)', 'Hellu Coffee', 'Pestle & Mortar Society', 'Omoté Soho (Velocity)', 'Le Matin Patisserie (ION Orchard)', 'KEK Keng Eng Kee Seafood (Tampines)', 'Mother-In-Law Egg Tart (Havelock)', 'Mono Izakaya', 'Daily Staples', "Ben's Tavern", 'FiftyFive Coffee Bar', 'Butcher’s Block', 'There Was No Coffee', 'Roemah Makan', 'Overscoop (Hougang)', 'Wong Fu Fu', 'Dim Sum Haus (Upper Weld)', 'Long Phung Vietnamese Restaurant (Chinatown)', 'Abundance (Jalan Besar)', 'Beans Factory', 'XiabuXiabu', 'B/W Bagelwich', 'Nakiryu', 'Fiamma (Capella Singapore)', 'Kei Kaisendon (Breadtalk IHQ)', 'cloud', 'Sweedy Patisserie', 'Fatty Patty (The Bedok Marketplace)', 'afterwords', 'NAN YANG DAO (Aljunied)', 'KREME', 'Pilot Kitchen', 'Peacock North Indian Cuisine (NEWest)', 'Café Natsu (Clemenceau)', 'Little Cart Noodle House', 'Anchovies & Peanuts (Golden Mile Food Centre)', 'Otto Pizza', 'Little French Fusion', 'Underdog Inn', 'Sum Dim Sum', 'Seng House', 'Lor Mak Mak (Changi Village Hawker Centre)', 'Guriru', 'The Last Scoop', 'Darkness Dessert', 'Hatsu', 'Dan Lao (Maxwell Food Centre)', 'Chong Qing Xiao Mu Deng Traditional Hot Pot (GR.iD)', 'Refuel J9 (Junction Nine)', 'Fu Xiao Xian', 'Good Chai People', 'Ginger.Lily', 'Paris Van Java', 'Hejio', 'LUNA (Joo Chiat)', 'The Better Scoop (Serangoon)', 'Beccarino Patisserie', 'Yi Qian Private Dining', 'HUSK Nasi Lemak (Bugis Cube)', 'Kong Cafe (Thomson Plaza)', 'Mooi Pâtisserie', 'Wanpo Tea Shop (Lazada One)', 'The Hainan Story Coffee House (NEX)', 'Hong Kong Zhai Dim Sum (Marina Square)', 'Beauty in The Pot (NEX)', 'GaiBang (Paya Lebar Square)', 'Sugaroses Cafe', 'SWIRLGO', 'Victoria Bakery', 'Dirty Cheesecake Bakery & Cafe', 'Kao Ge Yu (East Village)', 'Wonders', 'Parliament Bar', 'Mr. Bucket Chocolaterie (Dempsey)', 'Chapter 1', 'Qi Xiang Hotpot', 'The DEN - Kway Teow Kia & Bar', 'Yamakita - Tempura x Tapas', 'Onigarazu Don (Senja Hawker Centre)', 'Full Circle by J-man', 'Ah Lock Kitchen (Senja Hawker Centre)', "Winner's Fried Chicken", 'Jane Deer', 'Uncle Leong Seafood (Techview)', 'Hub & Spoke Cafe (Changi Airport T2)', 'Nani Bowl', 'Staple', 'Daniu Teochew Seafood Restaurant', '123 Zô Vietnamese BBQ Skewers and Hotpot', 'TwoBakeBoys (CT Hub 2)', 'Canopy (Changi City Point)', 'Capital Kitchen (Clarke Quay)', '8Bar Espresso', 'Boms & Buns', 'Lau Wang Claypot (Bugis+)', 'La Lola Churreria (Cross Street Exchange)', "Dawn's", 'Heng Heng Kueh', 'Fosters Cafe', 'MUGUNG', 'Sakutto Tempura&Oyster', 'Firewood Chicken & Bagel', 'Shikar', 'Ahara', '1-V:U', 'Cocokata', 'MANAM', 'Shake Shake In A Tub (IMM)', '929 Desserts & Bites', "Verandah @ Rael's (111 Somerset)", 'Kei Kaisendon (Tanglin Mall)', 'Lee Lai Jiak', 'Gelatology Lab', 'Matchaya (Jem)', 'Bag Me Up', 'PaPa Gelare by CoffeePlus', 'Chun Noodle Bar (Amoy Street Food Centre)', 'Butter Bean (VivoCity)', 'OMU NOMU Craft Sake & Raw Bar', 'The Dim Sum Place (The Centrepoint)', 'Yuugo Cafe', 'That Wine Place', 'The Whole Kitchen (CBD)', 'Colobaba (Century Square)', 'Boomeranz Nasi Ayam Power By Adimann (Northpoint City)', 'Hitoyoshi Izakaya', 'popotatoe', 'Jin Yu Man Tang Dessert Shop (South Bridge)', 'LILY•S Gourmet Bistro (Tanglin Mall)', 'Surrey Hills Deli', 'Main Street Commissary', 'Seroja', 'Luckmeow (Maxwell)', 'Old Shifu Charcoal Porridge', 'iSTEAKS Reserved', 'Rumours Beach Club', 'Willy Wankerz', 'Cupping Room Coffee Roasters (Robinson Centre)', 'Monte Risaia', 'Shinya Izakaya', 'OSTERIA BBR by Alain Ducasse', '+886 Bistro', 'Dabao Gelato', '99 Thai Taste']
```

Comment: the problem is because `OP` gets stale element exception after the click. but your code solves that anyway.

Comment: Can I check how to I scrap other details such as location/reviews/price